# Add Image to External Objects

Tags: apex, images, document, externalobjects

I have created an External Object `Customer` . I need to add documents as well such as passport pic & pdf document. 
The data is now saved as binary from the database that I load data from.

My question is, how can I display these images from my external object and what should I mark their column as, if this doesn't work , how can I link a set of documents from an external database to an External object `Customer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading , Salesforce currently doesn't support attachements & notes. Until then will have to get them via API from a visual force page or simply use a custom object instead